# Is a Transit Visa for China for Azerbaijan citizens required?

Tags: visas, transit, china, azerbaijan

I am an Azerbaijan citizen and a permanent resident of Russia. I am considering the following flight:

Indonesia (DPS) -> Baiyun (CAN) -> Russia (SVO)

I have an 8-hour layover in China, at Baiyun.

Do I need a transit visa? Because it says that Azerbaijan citizens who are flying through Xiamen need a visa. But I'm transiting through Baiyun. HELP ME PLEASE.

Based on [this website](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/RU-Russian-Fed.-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm):

> "This TWOV facility does not apply to nationals of Afghanistan, Azerbaijan, Iran, Iraq, Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, Malaysia, Oman, Pakistan, Saudi Arabia, Sri Lanka, Syria, Thailand, Turkiye, Turkmenistan and Yemen transiting through Xiamen (XMN)."

But based on [this website](https://ca.ceair.com/newCMS/ca/en/content/en_Footer/AboutMoreInfomation/201903/t20190305_2981.html):

> There are 24 countries that don't need a visa for transit through China.

Comment: First of all, can you confirm that the two flights are on a single ticket? That can change things a lot in certain situations.

Comment: Two flight on the same ticket. And I also have resident permit in Russia. That can help me in Chinese for transit?

Comment: In the first link I found a site for visa requirements in the Chinese airports, I added my ticket information, arrival and departure date, time etc. and there was this information

Answer (score 3):

The first link your posted (the IATA Travel Centre) gives you the information from Timatic, one of the databases used by airlines to decide what documents they require from passengers before boarding (passports, visas, etc.).

As you read, it states that most passengers transit through a Chinese airport within 24 hours, staying “airside” (I.e. not requiring to get their bags or check-in again), can transit without a visa.

There are a few airports where this is not possible (which do not include CAN), and a few nationalities who are excluded only if they transit at XMN. Not your concern, since you transit via CAN.

[Traveldoc](https://www.traveldoc.aero/) (another database used by airlines) says the same thing. If you enter DPS->CAN and CAN->SVO and Azerbaijani citizenship, it says it’s fine. If you try the same thing with a stop at XMN instead, it says you need a visa, so it agrees with Timatic.

The second page you linked to is for a longer 144-hour (6 days) visa free transit. That one is indeed restricted to specific citizenships but also to specific cities/regions in China, but it does not concern you, the 24-hour airside visa-free transit is enough for you.

So you are perfectly fine to perform this connection without a visa. There are however still Covid-related forms and procedures.

Comment: if this possible, you'll save my life man. i will call tomorrow the airline services. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about 2 different things: an airside transit and TWOV – the latter allows you to enter China and visit for up to 6 days. Azerbaijan citizens are not eligible, as both links you provide show, but that doesn't matter to you, since you should stay airside anyway.

For airside transits up to 24 hours you do not need a visa. In the case of Guangzhou, you can stay within the secure area (it's not always the case: I remember have to enter China to transit between Terminals 1 and 4 in Beijing Capital).